# Image classification / detection - Objects being used in real life vs. stock photo images?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, object-detection

When training detection models, are images that are used in real life better (i.e. higher accuracy / mAP) than images of the same object but in the form of stock photo?

[image]

Comment: If you want your model to recognize all of them, you must train with all of them.

Comment: It seems that the ones with white background will be easier to detect. Less chance of other features being false positives.

Comment: What kind of network do you use?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko TF object detection API w/ Faster RCNN ResNet 101

Answer (score 2):

The more variety the better. If you train a network on images that all have a white background and expect it to perform under conditions with noisy backgrounds you should expect the results on unseen data to perform worse because the network never had a chance to learn distinguiting features of target object vs. background objects.

If you have images with transparent backgrounds one form of data augmentation that would be expected to improve results would be to place that image against many random backgrounds. The closer you come to realistic renderings of an image the better you can expect your results to be.

The more realistic examples you can augment your training dataset with, the better. Note that it generally does not help to add random noise to your data to generate larger training datasets, it only improves results when your expanded dataset contains realistic variants of the original images in the dataset.

My motto when training neural networks is this: The network will cheat any chance it gets. It will learn impressively well, but given the opportunity, it will take shortcuts. Don't let it take shortcuts. That often translates to: Make the problem harder such that no shortcut exists for it to take. Neural networks often perform better under more difficult conditions because the simplest solution it can arrive at is also the most general purpose. Read up on multi-task learning for some exciting examples that provide great food-for-thought.